# Bootstrap3 accordion collapse: how to show opened div at the top?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I have just implemented bootstrap collapse(accordion) which works very well.
Every element has huge amount data, so that the data can't show from first

Is there any option to show element at the top when open accordion ?

Opened div should be top of the page

Demo **http://bootply.com/84308**

Comment: Please use fiddle or http://Bootply.com to show us your code

Comment: @Skelly just add link demo. Thanks for your comment. 
The opened div should be at top of the page

Answer (score 2):

You could capture the 'shown' event and use jQuery to move the selected panel to the first position in the accordion like this..

```
$('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {

  var openPanel = $(this).find('.in').parents('.panel');
  openPanel.prependTo('#accordion');

});
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/84308

Comment: No need to move div with in display. Just simply move visible area like `scrollTo` or something like that. Thanks a lot for you effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can add "in" class to your inner div to display data.
recommend you to go through the link
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#collapse

Please add more details to your problem if this does not helps you.
Thanks.

Comment: thanks for you answer. I have just updated my question. Please take a look.

Comment: hope you understand the question